# Does mean of uncountable infinite equal to infinite, which is known in calculus?

Tags: calculus, limits, elementary-set-theory

As I understand, the number of all infinite lentgh sequences which is consist of $\left\{1,2\right\}$ is uncountable.
I want to learn, Does mean of uncountable infinite equal to infinite, which is known in calculus?

I mean for example,

Let, $N$ be a number of all infinite lentgh sequences which is consist of $\left\{1,2\right\}$.

> Then, can we say ?
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{N}{2^n}=1 $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these are completely different concepts. $N$ is not a *number*. There is no such thing as the "number of all infinite length sequences of $\{1,2\}$. What you could talk about is the *cardinality* of the set of all infinite length sequences of $\{1,2\}$.

However, if you define $N$ to be a cardinality, then the expression $\frac{N}{2^n}$ is undefined, and thus the limit you are asking for does not exist.

Comment: I mean for example, $n=5$. We have $2^5$ possible finite sequence. Then if $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @Elementary If $n=5$, then the expression $\frac{N}{2^5}$ is nonsensical.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3286436/548054