# Is this limit correct: $\lim_{n\to\infty} {N(n)}/{2^n}=1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, limits, elementary-set-theory, infinity

> Is there a mathematical difference $n\to\infty$ between $n=\infty$ if we deduce that all infinite sequences consisting of elements $\left\{1,2\right\}$, which is for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $2^n$ possible finite sequences. But, if we include $n\to\infty$ or  $(n=\infty)$ we have uncountable infinite sequences.

Here, the question may seem ridiculous. I'm trying to say:

Let, $N(n)$ be a counting function of all possible sequences, for the given $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

> A) Therefore, is this limit correct ?
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty \\ n\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{N(n)}{2^n}=1$$
>
> B) For $n\to\infty$, can we say
> $N(n)=\text{uncountable infinity}?$

Comment: there's a mathematical definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ but not $n=\infty$ in this context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your confusion (especially in your comments to J. W. Tanner's answer) is that you're failing to distinguish between a *limit* and a *value at infinity*. You have
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \bigl(\text{number of functions }A\to\{1,2\}\text{ when }|A|=n \bigr) = \aleph_0 $$
taken as a limit of cardinal numbers when $n$ runs through $\mathbb N$. On the other hand
$$ \bigl(\text{number of functions }A\to\{1,2\}\text{ when }|A|=\aleph_0 \bigr) \ne \aleph_0 $$
In other words you *can't assume* that you can find a property of an infinity such as $\aleph_0$ by *taking a limit* of smaller cardinalities that *tend to* $\aleph_0$. This is not particularly mysterious; is just means that the "number of functions to $\{1,2\}$" function is *not continuous* at $\aleph_0$.

We can see the same effect for limits at finite real numbers; for example
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \lfloor 1-x^2\rfloor = 0 \qquad \text{but} \qquad \lfloor 1-0^0\rfloor = 1 $$

(where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the "largest integer $\le x$" function).

---

It is often but not always the case when we have a particular function $f$ that it makes sense to *define* the value of $f$ "at infinity" as $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$. Then the equality would hold by definition. But this is not an universal truth, just a convention of phrasing that's sometimes useful. And when our conception of $f$ *already has a good meaning* when we plug in an infinity, then there's no guarantee that this meaning will be the same as a limit.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95932/discussion-on-answer-by-henning-makholm-is-this-limit-correct-lim-n-to-infty).

Answer (score 1):

If $N(n)=2^n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, then, yes, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac {N(n)}{2^n}$ is defined and equals $1$.

But remember that $\infty$ is not an element of $\mathbb N$, and you have defined $N(n)$ only for $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: So, uncountable infinity$ =\infty$?

Comment: I see you edited your original question, but as I indicated, $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ has a specific definition; we do not say $n=\infty$; if you are talking about set cardinality, usually that is demonstrated according to whether a bijection exists

Comment: I 'm a novice. Is it possible , to add  little more details?..Thank you.

Comment: For definition of limits as $\infty$ is approached, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_at_infinity), whereas [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356715/2-mathbbn-is-uncountable-power-set-of-natural-numbers) is a demonstration that $2^\Bbb N$ is uncountable -- I think that's what you're after

Comment: So, for $n\to\infty, N(n)$ is uncountable. As I understand correct?

Comment: The power set of a countably infinite set is uncountable, but it is finite for all finite sets

Comment: I understood you. But, I never seen $n\to\infty$ in set theory. For this reason I wanted to ask.  Actually, I can  not define $N(n)$ well.